# Asp NET MVC - Check credentials again in Admin Area

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have Asp.NET MVC app with authorization. Any User can log in. Only Admins role can see Admin Area in app. But I need that it will be second check for password if enter the Admin Area - if user with role "Admin" enter Admin area - he must to enter his password again.

What the simplest way to do this?
Anybody can help me?

Thank you.

Comment: If this is for admins only, the easiest way may be a session variable. User is already authenticated, you just want an extra verification. If variable is not set, user needs to enter credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Example:
Create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`:

```
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class AdminAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)//every request which has Authorize attribute is filter hear
        {

            var routeData = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;//get RouteData
            var area = routeData.DataTokens["area"];

            bool isAdmin = area != null && area.ToString() == "Admin"
                && filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
                && filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin");// check admin role and admin area

            if (!isAdmin && area != null && area.ToString() == "Admin")
            {//if and only if role =admin and area=admin 

                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {//if ajax request set Forbidden( http code 403)
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;//.NET 4.5+
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
                }
                else
                {
                    // redirect any route like login action
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
                    {
                        {"action", "Login"},
                        {"controller", "Account"},
                        {"area", ""}
                    });// change and write where you want to redirect
                }

            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }


        }

    }
```

Add into `FilterConfig`.

**FilterConfig.cs:**

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AdminAuthorizeAttribute());//add filter globaly
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can add some explanation to the code. How is this going to force an additional login for an already authenticated user (with the role "Admin")?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg i updat my code and put comment every section. i think it's enough.